# What does "ain't but" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the second episode of the second season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Otis: Nearest hospital went up in flames a month ago. The High School
>
> Hershel: That's what I was thinking. They set up a fema shelter there.
> They would have everything we need
>
> Otis: Place was overrun last time I saw it. You couldn't get near it.
> Maybe It's better now
>
> Shane: I said,leave the rest to me. Is It too late to take that back?
>
> Rick: I hate you going alone
>
> Shane: Come on. Doc,why don't you do me a list and draw me a map?
>
> Otis: You won't need a map. I'll take you there. **Ain't but** five miles.

Comment: It's a dialectal "double negation", where ***but** = **only*** *(it is [NOT] only 5 miles)* - same as ***I ain't got no money*** *(I have [NOT] no money)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ain't but" (is not but) is an American rural dialect colloquialism meaning "is only". The speaker could also have said "it is but five miles" with the same meaning. Consider "but" to mean "only" when used this way.